# No such file or directory when calling method from inside JSP

Tags: java, html, file

I have a package (not the default package) that has a class Data and a method getData() which relies on a certain .txt file to read from. I have that .txt file located in the Data package itself. When I call method getData() from a main method of Data, it works fine and returns the proper result.

However, when I call Data.getData() from inside a JSP, it throws a "No such file or directory" error, saying it cant find the .txt file. I have tried putting that .txt file in the WebContent package, but that didn't work. What is the problem here?

Comment: you just need to specify the url for the file that is relative to the current directory of your jsp

Comment: It does not work in the JSP if I do new File("./Package/TextFile.txt").  It does not even work if I do new File("./WebContent/TextFile.txt") (I put TexttFile in WebContent folder). It only works if I do new File("/Users/RajRaina/Desktop/File/Package/TextFile.txt""). But this will not work on other peoples computers. What exactly should I do then? How can I use the relative path, found in the Properties of the textfile, to make this robust?